# Synchronising two threads accessing the same resource

Tags: java, multithreading

I have an application which is like a web browser of sorts. Users point it at a page and it displays content for that page. It also periodically refreshes if the user doesn't do anything.

Since users could potentially switch page at any time, the application can have up to 3 threads at once:

1. UI thread
2. Thread **A**, which runs periodically, fetches information about the current page, then updates the app
3. Thread **B**, which runs when the user switches page, fetches information about the next page, then updates the app

As you can see, the application's data model could be updated from either **A** or **B** at any one time, if the periodic update happens while switching is in progress. The updates aren't atomic (a bunch of fields are set) so this causes information about the next and current pages to be mixed up, and the app's state becomes inconsistent overall.

How best would I synchronise these updates? A few extra details:

- I'm using the Executor framework, and I'm not sure how to communicate across threads, join, synchronise, etc. with it.
- I've tried stopping **A** before **B** starts, then restarting it after **B** completes, with `executor.shutdown(); executor.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.DAYS)` but it didn't seem to work.

Comment: Is `synchronized` not enough here?

Comment: Please, show _minimal_ version of code you have this issue with.

Comment: Sometimes when you can't figure out how to synchronize two or more threads, it's because you don't really need them.  Q: What does thread A do that can't be done by the UI thread in response to a periodic timer event?  Q: What does thread B do that can't be done in the UI thread in response to the mouse-click or key-press that means "switch page".  And, if there _is_ something that you can't do in the UI thread, are you sure it can't be done in your GUI framework's "invokeLater" function?